# Which class contains Bootstraps collapsed menu style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

sorry for asking this simple question but I can not figure it out.

Which css class is responsible for the collapsed menu item (not the normal)?

For the normal menu I am using this style to display a colored border:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
background-color: #232932;  
color:white;
height:80px;
border-top:5px solid #77d757;
padding-top:25px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
background-color: #232932;  
color:white;
height:80px;
border-top:5px solid #e20017;
padding-top:25px;
}
```

But I do not want to display this border on the collapsed menu item...

Comment: you mean this class : `collapse navbar-collapse`
if yes check : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: No sorry I don't think this is what I mean, I updated my question a little bit more precise...

Comment: Are you looking for the section of the navbar that goes away on smaller screens, or the section that stays? I assume you mean the section that stays, and I don't believe there is a CSS class for that. You're probably best off with using media queries for the appropriate selectors.

Comment: Use a @media query, see this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448499/style-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-witout-applying-that-styling-to-collapsed-navbar/14448630#14448630

Answer (score 0):

I might be incorrect, but I believe you're looking for the `in` class with the selector `navbar-default navbar-collapse.in`.

This extra `in` class shows up only when the collapsed navbar is expanded using the button that appears. You may also, however, run into problems because there is a third class: `collapsing` with the selector `navbar-collapse.collapsing` which shows up while the menu is expanding. I'm guessing you don't want your borders to show up during that process as well.

Bootstrap adds these two classes (`in` and `collapsing`, respectively) when the menu is active, and therefore it has a stronger CSS selector.

Hopefully i'm understanding you correctly!

Comment: I think obviously this is what I am searching, but it is not working. Here is a picture of the problem. The upper menu is the normal menu (the menu for desktop computers etc.), and below the collapsed. The normal menu shows the red and green borders which are also shown in the collapsed menu. That is my problem... And here is the picture: http://www.picfront.org/d/93rG

Comment: This helped me. I had to be very specific in my CSS to make sure I overrode bootstraps classes. `.navbar-collapse.collapsing > ul > li > a.my-button` and `.navbar-collapse.collapse.in > ul > li > a.my-button`