# Apply CSS only to non collapsed menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to apply css rules to my navbar menu, but I do not wish for them to show on the collapsed menu. Using the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448499/style-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-witout-applying-that-styling-to-collapsed-navbar) I tried the following:

```
@media (min-width: 980px) {
    /* your conditional CSS*/
}
```

However if my browser windows is at 900px, the collapsed menu isn't show and therefore my CSS isn't shown. Here is the code for my menu:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header_links">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header_links">
...
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

How can I reliably only apply CSS rules to my menu when it isn't collapsed?

Comment: Have you tried applying your conditional css under `@media (min-width: 900px) {...`?

Comment: It actually still doesn't collapse until 768px, so I guess the min-width: 768px would fix it for me. I'm worried though that at different zooms/browsers this 768 might be different?

Comment: Yeah. I mentioned 900 since that's what you have in your question. When you zoom, media queries are not affected unless you use ems. But with pixels, they simple act as if you're on a different width. So if you design your media queries for those widths, its should work accordingly. You can test your media queries with zoom here: http://mediaqueriestest.com/

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. So where does the 768px come from? Is that the standard bootstrap width for collapsing the menu?

Comment: That's the width for phones and small tablets. See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying your conditional css under `@media (min-width: 900px) {...` ?

Here's a sample that changes the background color of the navbar once its at least 900px wide:
http://www.bootply.com/Xt0oIHkhjs